# "Install new software error" with eclipse indigo/juno RCP

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I tried to update software in eclipse RCP, but I got this error.

[image]

The Error log says that some of the feature.xml files are missing.
[image]

I opened one of the error log to find this.
[image]

And actually, some file names in the features directory are not xml, but xml_.
[image]

I tried the juno and indigo eclipse RCP, but I have the same error message, and same xml_ files. I use eclipse on Mac OS X.

What's wrong? How can I make it to update software in eclipse?

Comment: can you post error log in a better way.. ? i mean.. copy stack traces of indivisual exception and post.. a couple of them maybe?

Comment: seems like some config mismatch.. nothing much clear.. would you want to uninstall the existing and then install the latest rather than upgrading the current?

Comment: Actually, I didn't install anything, as I just downloaded RCP and tried to execute "Install New Software". Could you teach me how to uninstall the existing plugins/tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was from extracting downloaded tar file. I used pathfinder for untar it, but something might be wrong. I used `tar xvf` and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Go to help->check for update (if you want to update ) 
 help->install new software (if the updated software is available you can download it)
and if the problem persist try to install eclipse indigo rcp and  again from the site and install it.Hope it might help you.

Comment: update/install new software gives me the same error message. And I downloaded and tested indigo/juno RCP multiple times. The results are the same, and other versions of eclipse are working fine.