# What makes eclipse for RCP different from eclipse classic?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I understand that I need RCP for eclipse plugin and eclipse RCP development. However, as I have [some crashes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/67104/eclipse-rcp-juno-64-bit-crashes-on-mac-os-x), and [software installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862152/install-new-software-error-with-eclipse-indigo-juno-rcp) issues, I guess I have to use eclipse classic until the issues are solved.

What makes eclipse for RCP different from eclipse classic? 
I checked eclipse download page, and to me it seems like that eclipse classic doesn't have any feature whereas RCP has a lot.

[image]
[image]

Are the features only difference between the two choices?
If so, can I download the features/plugins to use all the RCP features in eclipse classic without any problems?

Comment: If you don't need to develop Eclipse plugins, seems like you'd need [the package for Java](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/junosr1) or the one for [Java EE](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junosr1). Eclipse Classic looks like a legacy configuration, without the new goodies that are useful for general development, and with PDT that most people don't need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the downloads on the eclipse.org page are only predefined packages of generally available Eclipse plugins. So you can always install *any* plugin into *any* existing Eclipse installation (assuming no dependency conflicts). The package selection on the download site only determines what is pre-installed (and it is hard to disable the pre-installed features).

For RCP development you need the JDT and PDE features. Both the "classic" as well as "for RCP development" packages contain those, so it is still your choice.

If you really want a minimalistic Eclipse suited to your needs, then install the "Platform Runtime Binary" from http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.2.1-201209141800/, which is an "empty" Eclipse. Afterwards install only your chosen plugins using the update manager.

Comment: How does the `eclipse features` work in this? Is `eclipse feature` the same as `eclipse software`?

Comment: Eclipse "features" are the smallest _installable_ pieces of Eclipse applications for users (e.g. the Java development toolkit). They consist of multiple plugins, where plugins are the smallest pieces that make sense from the _developers_ point of view (e.g. org.eclipse.jdt.core, org.eclipse.jdt.ui, org.eclipse.jdt.somethingelse).